# How can I only list files with complementary extensions?

Tags: bash, file-listing

In a directory, I have a bunch of files like file1.tex, file1.pdf, file2.tex, file2.pdf etc along with other files. I want, preferably a one liner in bash (to include in a make file as dependency), to

1. list  all tex files if their pdf versions are also available.
2. list all pdf files if their tex versions are also available.

EDIT

I had tried

```
find . \( -name '*.pdf' -name '*.tex' \)
```

but it did not work. I guess the above approach is useful if I want to find files with pdf **or** tex extensions by using the -o option between two name switches. 
thanks

suresh

Comment: In the future, please include what you have tried, as well as any error messages or failing sample sets, along with your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Solution

This isn't very readable--it would be much better to make this a script or shell function with some decent line wrapping--but you can force the loop to be a one-liner if you really want to.

```
# List TeX files with matching PDFs.
for file in *.pdf; do [ -f "${file/.pdf}.tex" ] && ls "${file/.pdf/.tex}"; done

# List PDFs with matching TeX files.
for file in *.tex; do [ -f "${file/.tex}.pdf" ] && ls "${file/.tex/.pdf}"; done
```

### Validating the Solution

You can quickly test that the solution works properly with with some sample data.

```
$ touch file1.pdf file1.tex file2.pdf file2.tex file3.pdf file4.tex

$ for file in *.pdf; do [ -f "${file/.pdf}.tex" ] && ls "${file/.pdf/.tex}"; done
file1.tex
file2.tex

$ for file in *.tex; do [ -f "${file/.tex}.pdf" ] && ls "${file/.tex/.pdf}"; done
file1.pdf
file2.pdf
```

Note that in both cases, files without complements in the other format are silently ignored.

Comment: I have added what I tried. I guess without loops it is not possible to do.